# accessing Facebook through Java application

Tags: java, facebook

could someone help me on this problem,

i want to access facebook API through java application. i was looking for java implementation similar to that twitter is having, does anyone have an experience on connecting fb using something like fb4j.jar.

I highly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented a photo import from FB using http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api

It was not easy though as the examples/doco are quite out of date and the authorisation and FB API in general are very confusing.

There's several ways to 'integrate' with facebook e.g. an actual FB application vs facebook connect (login via FB).

What specifically are you trying to do?

cheers

Lee

Comment: hi leebutts, i need to update fb profile data through java application, do you have some idea on how do this, could you share your experience with us

Comment: yeah it was very confusing for me too to use Java (Google app engine) with facebook api. But once you understand the essence of XFBML and Canvas app, and how cookies are passed between your server and facebook server, then it will make more sense.

Comment: Because I'm working on a Grails app, I based my code on Nimble's facebook login code: http://code.google.com/p/nimble/

Once you have a FacebookJsonRestClient object setup the API is pretty easy to use, it was just the authentication that I struggled with originally (until I had a read through the Nimble code).

cheers

Lee